# unable to launch dockerized node app in browser

Tags: node.js, macos, docker

I am not able to launch dockorize node app. I have removed docker toolkit and installed docker native to MAC

docker-compose.yml web setting

```
services:  
  web:
    image: node:boron
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/apicode   
    depends_on:
      - db
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    tty: true
```

when I run 
`docker-compose run web` 
on command line , I can see the container launched.

What I am getting confused about is missing port mapping. I feel MAC is not able to reach container to serve the request ...

docker inspect hostname

```
 "Path": "/bin/bash",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            **"Status": "running",**
            "Running": true,

 CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND     CREATED STATUS       PORTS    
 b61db44d38a7   node:boron  "/bin/bash" About a minute ago
```

Expected

```
 CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND     CREATED STATUS       PORTS    
 b61db44d38a7   node:boron  "/bin/bash" About a minute ago      3000:3000
```

http://localhost:3000 is expected to load the page.

My code is under /users dir of MAC so it is mounted correctly.

## Whats wrong...

```
docker log [id]
root@d838:/# exit
exit
```

Comment: Are you running docker compose? `docker-compose up `. Also, bash will not run your app. Are you running the app manually in the container?

Comment: Update post with docker logs with  ```docker logs id_container``` .

Comment: @juliansalas added in question

Comment: @Robert I am runing docker-compose run web command

Comment: I belive that you have to add docker command in docker-compose to hold container, For instance command: ```ng server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200  --live-reload-port 49153```